# LSTM classification for 2D dataset

Tags: python-2.7, keras, lstm

I a dataset with 10000 rows and 4 features (positions of two cars and their velocity) as  x_train and also y_train is my labels which is 0 or 1. I want with LSTM classifying my dataset but the accuracy do not go more than 50 percent. For LSTM I tested both input_shape (10000, 4, 1) and (10000, 1, 4) but accuracy remains around 50 percentage. Do you know what should I do to improve the accuracy? and which of (10000, 4, 1) and (10000, 1, 4) are correct format ?

```
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, label, test_size=0.25, random_state=42)
x_train = x_train.reshape(-1, 4, 1)
x_test  = x_test.reshape(-1, 4, 1)
y_train = y_train.reshape(-1, 1, 1)
y_test = y_test.reshape(-1, 1, 1) 

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(256, input_shape=(x_train.shape[1:]), activation='tanh', return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(LSTM(256, activation='tanh'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dense(128, activation='tanh'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))
model.compile( loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'] )
history = model.fit(x_train, y_train, validation_split=0.33, epochs=20, batch_size=128,shuffle=True )
```

Comment: `model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))` as last layer

Comment: Thank you that raised the accuracy to 95%. Is it normal to add sigmoid after the softmax layer?

Comment: No, this was meant to replace your current last layer, sorry for my lack of clarity

Comment: so you mean instead of softmax, I should put sigmoid?     model. add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')).  Then if true, my data set has two-class " safe and unsafe" then is it ok to assign just 1 neuron for output? ( if I assign 2 my I receive error )